# uber-android integration:service-error occur when try to register app in uber console

Tags: android, uber-api

I would like to integrate uber in my app. I register my app in uber developer console (https://developer.uber.com/apps/) but an error will occur like `service.error`. When I create another new app pressing `+NEW APP` button, the error will also appear. How do I resolve it?

Image in console is attached below :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have created several apps on my account. I've seen this a couple of times over the past few weeks; always immediately after creating a new app.

It seems to fix itself in time, so my advice would be to just give it a day or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Uber SDK for Android Click [here](https://github.com/Neno0o/Uber-Android-SDK). Note that this SDK still in beta-version.